# Image sizing for web application

Tags: php, html, css, image

I use php and framework named "laravel 5.0".
There is a great package for gd library, and I can resize or add some grey filter.

Now I'm about to create the web app and use a few types of sizes of images such as the image for thumnbnaill, the image within navbar, images for the userlist.

So I just wonder what the best practice for this ?

Sure I can resize images with css/js each time browser outputs the page?
(But the rendering speed must be slower.)

or should I store the path for different sizes of image in db ?
(But what if I change the interface design in the future.)

or better ways to approach to this image handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I use is to always save the original picture alongside all resized versions. Thus when you change layout and need for another image sizes emerges, you can always run a script to create new sizes based on the original picture.

And I also suggest to save to database dimensions (width, height) of each variant as well. Therefore you can directly put it in HTML attributes width and height and your layout wont be bouncing whilst loading.

How you save the path to your images is really up to you, you don't have to save path at all - sometimes it's sufficient to save the image name (or just use ID) and image extension. The paths to different image sizes may be stored in PHP constants. This way you avoid duplicity of saving the same path in database million times because you will use an easy to change constant.